# How do I make this video work on Firefox (Mac) and Chrome (Windows)?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, media

CODE:

```
<video controls width="100%">
                <source src="/learn/guide/test.mp4">
                    <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
            </video>
```

The above works on everything except Firefox on Mac and Chrome on Windows.

On Firefox for Mac I get the following error message:

```
no video with supported format and mime type found
```

On Chrome for Windows I get the following error message:

```
the video cannot be found it may have been removed from the server.
```

The chrome error doesn't make sense since it's working on all other browsers.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have alternate source files?  Firefox (Mac) cannot play .mp4.  [a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support)

Chrome can.  Have you tried other browsers on that same Windows computer?  Ensure you have network connectivity to wherever that path goes, and reboot, if you must.

Answer (score 0):

While I only use [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) for Audio currently, this type of situation is exactly what it was made for.

One drawback is you need to maintain several file formats, but this mainly concerns browser limitations. AFAIK you can't use MP4 in all common browsers. Mediaelement.js is not really for streaming either.